# c++ opencv videoCapture.isOpend() always return false

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

cap.isOpend() always returns false

I run it with the following instructions:

~/Projects/git-repo/opencv/test$ cmake .

~/Projects/git-repo/opencv/test$ make

~/Projects/git-repo/opencv/test$ ./PlayVideo

output is:

error reading video file

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include<iostream>

int main(void) {

    cv::VideoCapture capVideo;


    capVideo.open("/home/fateme/Projects/git-repo/opencv/test/osm.mp4");

    if (!capVideo.isOpened()) {                                                 // if unable to open video file
        std::cout << "\nerror reading video file" << std::endl << std::endl;      // show error message

        return(0);                                                              // and exit program
    }

 }
```

this is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( PlayVideo PlayVideo.cpp )
target_link_libraries( PlayVideo ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: Please check if codec for MP4 is installed on your system.

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes I installed VLC and mp4 played

Comment: `cv::getBuildInformation()`, video I/O section, please [edit] and add the info -- VLC does not install codecs into the system. MP4 is not a codec but a container format.